# My Google App Script is Duplicating a whole sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following app script to copy data from a certain range to another file. But for some reason this script is also copying and pasting the whole sheet. How to stop this?

```
function copyInfo() {
  var destinationSpreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189hJTiUlwubZdeN1HZ9n98U-gdaGdFSAu1-ARvlGMKo/edit#gid=0"; // Please set your Spreadsheet URL.
  var destinationSheetName = "RawDataCopyPaste"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Source sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Product-analyse");
  var temp1 = copySheet.copyTo(ss);
  var r = temp1.getDataRange();
  r.copyTo(r, { contentsOnly: true });

  // Destination sheet.
  var dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationSpreadsheetUrl);
  var dstSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  var temp2 = temp1.copyTo(dstSS);
  temp2.getRange(93, 6, 40, ).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 2, 1));

  // clear source values
  copySheet.getRange(1, 2, 300, 9)

}
```

Example Source Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EKvIACMU7DMfuK9SQk8o6mmTTQ8_8a1qPt2jWy_q2MU/edit#gid=495001425

Example Dest Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mSDRsHPiPUlqg94x1Ocdssxr7fMJhqztch7kd_Xh_cE/edit#gid=0

Comment: By the whole sheet you mean all the data from the spreadsheet? I am asking this because I can see that from the source sheet you are using `getDataRange()` so that would explain why you are getting the whole range instead of just a specific range as you said you needed. If not, I think an example of what the actual behavior and the desired behavior are would help us understand your request.

Comment: Yes, right now it is doing 2 things:

1. Copying the whole sheet "Product-analyse" and everything in this sheet and pasting it into the other file.
2. Copying the selected range (93,6,40) to the sheet in the other file. 

I only need the second one.

Comment: @Scraper2022 can you please provide a sample sheet so the community can better help you and reproduce/test this?

Comment: @YancyGodoy  added an example sheet. If you run the App Script "CopyInfo" you will see in the dest sheet it copies the text I ask for. But it also copies a new tab of the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function copyInfoToAnotherFile() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("dssid");
  const ssh = sss.getSheet("Sheet0");
  const svs = ssh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, svs.length,svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
}
```

Comment: I tried this formula. I only need it to copy 
Row starting at 93 + 40 
Columns starting at the 6th one + 5